# What is tty? Where is it used?

Tags: tty

I am a student and new to ubuntu. I read about tty command in the questions people posted earlier but couldn't understand the answers. Could anybody explain it in a more easy way? :)

Comment: Which questions did you read and what didn't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

This link might help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426280/what-do-pty-and-tty-mean

Some very good explanations there.

tty stands for teletype  - the original terminals used a line printer for output (as opposed to a screen or terminal as you find today) and a keyboard for input. A pty is a pseudo-terminal.

Both terms have survived the annals of time.